# Why is the multivariate normal distribution is $(\Sigma, C)$ sub-gaussian?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, bounds, subgaussianity

The definition of *sub-gaussian* from a book I work with is: $X\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is $(\Sigma,C)$ sub-gaussian if $$\mathbb{P}(\lvert X^\top u\rvert>t)<Ce^{-t^2/(2u^\top\Sigma u)}, \qquad u\in\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}, t>0.$$ And I wonder how I can show that $X\sim N(\mu,\Sigma)$ is $(\Sigma,C)$ sub-gaussian.

Comment: Welcome to CV, Torben. Have you [searched our site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=sub+gaussian)?  Several answers are available.

Comment: Do you mind specifying the information of the book you cited this definition from?

Comment: There is no further information available in the book.

Comment: @TorbenI What Zhanxiong means is "please tell us the title, author, and date of the book that you cited this definition from".